# The Android App handles being unable to load at startup badly

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I most often use the Android app over a mobile connection (4G) rather than wifi. *Sometimes,* my 4G drops out for a few seconds — the connection will remain active, but I won't be able to download anything. If I happen to launch the Android app during those seconds, the load screen will goof out:

- The normal load screen will show up for ~3-5 seconds.
- Then it will fade to a black screen, and stay like that.
- If it still can't load anything 20-30 seconds later, my phone will report that the Android app isn't responding and ask if I want to close it.
- If it manages  to start loading during this time, though, it'll successfully move on to the Feed, as it should.

It should probably just display the load screen for as long as it takes!

My phone's a HTC One running Android 4.3.

Comment: I ran into similar behavior during the DDoS outage yesterday.

Comment: I had this a few days ago, and assumed it was just a one-time thing. Now I realize that my phone was just switching from WiFi to 4G, so it temporarily lost connection. +1

Comment: I see this anytime I'm in a really bad service area.

Comment: This happens to me almost every day. I usually have to remove the app from recent apps list and start it again when this happens.

Comment: it says [tag:status-completed] but I still have it on Nexus 5, android 5.1.1